# wsadmin adminApp.update java.net.UnknownHostException Full-Qualified-Hostname

Tags: soap, deployment, websphere

Try to deploy an EAR file to WebSphere enterprise app, over a SOAP connection.

the command line:

```
call wsadmin -conntype SOAP -host %WAS_HOST% -port %WAS_PORT% -user %WAS_USER% -password !WAS_PASSWORD! -lang jython -c "AdminApp.update('%APP_NAME%', 'app', '[ -operation update -contents %EAR_FILE% -usedefaultbindings -defaultbinding.virtual.host default_host -nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination $(APP_INSTALL_ROOT)/%WAS_HOST%Network -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -deployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapModulesToServers [[ %MODULE_NAME% %WAR_FILE%,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=%WAS_HOST%Network,cluster=%CLUSTER%+WebSphere:cell=%WAS_HOST%Network,node=%WEB_NODE%,server=%WEB_NODE% ]]]' )"
```

is issued from a build machine that is on windows. where `WAS_HOST=MySrvrA.mycomp.com`

when running this command, I got

> WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node eagnmncom0cbbManager using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
>   WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminApp.update ...
>   ....
>   exception information: 
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.filetransfer.client.TransferFailedException
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: java.net.UnknownHostException: **MySrvrA**

the WebSphere App server is on Linux, and the /etc/hosts file has the contents:

> ## IP-Address  Full-Qualified-Hostname  Short-Hostname
>
> #
>
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> ## special IPv6 addresses ::1     localhost       ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
>
> fe00::0 ipv6-localnet
>
> ff00::0 ipv6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ipv6-allnodes ff02::2 ipv6-allrouters
>   ff02::3 ipv6-allhosts
>
> **56.xxx.xxx.xxx     MySrvrA.mycomp.com  MySrvrA**

**this server can be accessible over the internet via the Full-Qualified-Hostname only.**

To trouble shoot, I have

1) run a command of

```
call wsadmin -conntype SOAP -host %WAS_HOST% -port %WAS_PORT% -user %WAS_USER% -password !WAS_PASSWORD! -lang jython -c "print Help.help()"
```

this works, and it should prove that the connection from the build machine to the WAS server is good.

2) to further prove that the AdminApp.update and its resolved parameters works, I have run the AppAdmin.update in its entirety:

```
AdminApp.update('%APP_NAME%', 'app', '[ -operation update -contents %EAR_FILE% -usedefaultbindings -defaultbinding.virtual.host default_host -nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination $(APP_INSTALL_ROOT)/%WAS_HOST%Network -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -deployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapModulesToServers [[ %MODULE_NAME% %WAR_FILE%,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=%WAS_HOST%Network,cluster=%CLUSTER%+WebSphere:cell=%WAS_HOST%Network,node=%WEB_NODE%,server=%WEB_NODE% ]]]' )
```

directly on the WAS server. it works, and should prove the AdminApp.update and it's options and parameters are good.

it seems to me that over a SOAP deployment, AdminApp.update truncated the WAS_HOST and does not use the Full-Qualified-Hostname.

What I am doing wrong, and how can I resolve this?

I have another machine set that are accessible from the Internet via the Short-Hostname, the same command line works perfectly over SOAP connector.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a security restriction causes the issue.

The target WAS server is in DMZ .com, while the build machine is in the blue .xxx, file transfer from .xxx to .com is not allowed based on the security policies of the organization.

After adding the target WAS servers into the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts of the build machine, the deployment goes successfully.